# how to update to null in Bigquery using apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

There is no problem at all when inserting null data into Big Query using Apache Beam.

However, when we do up f"update 'dataset.table' set col1="value", col2="value" where condition", we find incompatibility between None (from Beam) and null from Big Query.

Is there a way around this problem and update null data from Apache Beam to Big Query?

Comment: did you try the  the Coalesce function ? The Coalesce function returns the first non-null value in a list of expressions. You can use this function to replace any null values with a default value before updating the table.

Here is an example query sql:
```UPDATE `dataset.table`
SET col1 = COALESCE(value1, "default_value1"),
    col2 = COALESCE(value2, "default_value2")
WHERE condition```
In this query, if value1 or value2 is null, it will be replaced with "default_value1" or "default_value2", respectively.

You can modify the default values as needed to fit your use case.

Comment: I haven't tried to coalesce it. Thanks for reminding me, I'll try it out